# OpenNMS Won't Recognize Nodes for SNMP Monitoring

Tags: windows, networking, snmp, opennms

My OpenNMS system is running on Windows Server 2012 and I am doing most of my configurations through the web interface.

I have configured an SNMP community associated with a range of ip addresses for the node I want to monitor. I have specified a string for this community. I have added the node (which contains multiple ip addresses) for provisioning. I have added the node to the default data collection group. However, when I try to navigate to the node, rescan it, and manage data collection per interface, I cannot view the node as an option from which to collect data. I also do not see SNMP data on the node availability graphs, only ICMP data. How should I approach this problem. Are there any additional files I need to edit?

If any of you have some knowledge of OpenNMS, I would appreciate the help. I have only been using OpenNMS for 2 weeks now, and I have very little knowledge of SNMP or networking, though I am learning more every day.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is important to ensure your OpenNMS as SNMP access to your Device you want to monitor. You can verify this by running the following command from the CLI off your OpenNMS server:

```
snmpwalk -v 2c -c <your-community-string> <your-ip-interface>
```

If you don't see any output or a timeout, you have connectivity issues which can be firewalls between your OpenNMS and the device you want to monitor. It can also be the SNMP Agent on your Device does not allow access from your OpenNMS servers IP address.

As I'm reading your Node has multiple IP interfaces you have provisioned. You can define an attribute "SNMP Primary" which means:

- P: It is the primary interface and when it is reachable, OpenNMS will try to fetch all SNMP performance data from this interface
- S: It is set as secondary, it means SNMP is available but will only be used to fetch SNMP performance data if the primary interface is down
- N: Not used for SNMP performance data collection

By default OpenNMS detects also services like SNMP. The SNMP service is assigned to the interface when it is possible to fetch the System Object ID (sysoid) `.1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2.0` from the given IP interface using the SNMP community you have configured by the IP address in the WebUI. You can troubleshoot this on the CLI using the `snmpget` command from your OpenNMS server like this:

```
snmpget -v 2c -c <your-community-string> <your-ip-interface> .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2.0
```

If you don't get a result, OpenNMS will not detect the SNMP service. OpenNMS will only try to collect SNMP performance data from an IP interface when the SNMP service is associated.

Hope this helps for further troubleshooting.